# NullPointerException Query in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

i got stuck in JSF login page, please help..

login.jsp

```
<f:view>
    <h:messages style="color: red"
                showDetail="true"/>
    <h:form id="login">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0">
            Username: <h:inputText id="nip"
                         value="#{peg.nip}"/>
            Password: <h:inputSecret id="passwd"
                           value="#{peg.passwd}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton id="submit" 
                         value="Login"
                         action="#{peg.login}"/>
        <br>
    </h:form>

</f:view>
```

pegawai.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pegawai")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Pegawai.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pegawai p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Pegawai.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Pegawai p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Pegawai.findByOtoritasId", query = "SELECT p FROM Pegawai p WHERE p.otoritasId = :otoritasId")})
public class Pegawai implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "nip")
    private String nip;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "nama_depan")
    private String namaDepan;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "nama_tengah")
    private String namaTengah;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "nama_belakang")
    private String namaBelakang;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "otoritas_id")
    private int otoritasId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "passwd")
    private String passwd;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pegawai")
    private Collection<Assets> assetsCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "jabatan_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Jabatan jabatan;
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Department department;

    public Pegawai() {
    }

    public Pegawai(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pegawai(Integer id, String nip, String namaDepan, int otoritasId, String passwd) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nip = nip;
        this.namaDepan = namaDepan;
        this.otoritasId = otoritasId;
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNip() {
        return nip;
    }

    public void setNip(String nip) {
        this.nip = nip;
    }

    public String getNamaDepan() {
        return namaDepan;
    }

    public void setNamaDepan(String namaDepan) {
        this.namaDepan = namaDepan;
    }

    public String getNamaTengah() {
        return namaTengah;
    }

    public void setNamaTengah(String namaTengah) {
        this.namaTengah = namaTengah;
    }

    public String getNamaBelakang() {
        return namaBelakang;
    }

    public void setNamaBelakang(String namaBelakang) {
        this.namaBelakang = namaBelakang;
    }

    public int getOtoritasId() {
        return otoritasId;
    }

    public void setOtoritasId(int otoritasId) {
        this.otoritasId = otoritasId;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public Collection<Assets> getAssetsCollection() {
        return assetsCollection;
    }

    public void setAssetsCollection(Collection<Assets> assetsCollection) {
        this.assetsCollection = assetsCollection;
    }

    public Jabatan getJabatan() {
        return jabatan;
    }

    public void setJabatan(Jabatan jabatan) {
        this.jabatan = jabatan;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Pegawai)) {
            return false;
        }
        Pegawai other = (Pegawai) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Assets.Entities.Pegawai[id=" + id + "]";
    }
```

pegawaimanager.java

```
public class PegawaiManager{
    private Integer id;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private Department department;
    private String nip;
    private String namaDepan;
    private String namaTengah;
    private String namaBelakang;
    private int otoritasId;
    private String passwd;
    private Jabatan jabatan;
    private Collection<Assets> assetsCollection;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNip() {
        return nip;
    }

    public void setNip(String nip) {
        this.nip = nip;
    }

    public String getNamaDepan() {
        return namaDepan;
    }

    public void setNamaDepan(String namaDepan) {
        this.namaDepan = namaDepan;
    }

    public String getNamaTengah() {
        return namaTengah;
    }

    public void setNamaTengah(String namaTengah) {
        this.namaTengah = namaTengah;
    }

    public String getNamaBelakang() {
        return namaBelakang;
    }

    public void setNamaBelakang(String namaBelakang) {
        this.namaBelakang = namaBelakang;
    }

    public int getOtoritasId() {
        return otoritasId;
    }

    public void setOtoritasId(int otoritasId) {
        this.otoritasId = otoritasId;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public Collection<Assets> getAssetsCollection() {
        return assetsCollection;
    }

    public void setAssetsCollection(Collection<Assets> assetsCollection) {
        this.assetsCollection = assetsCollection;
    }

    public Jabatan getJabatan() {
        return jabatan;
    }

    public void setJabatan(Jabatan jabatan) {
        this.jabatan = jabatan;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String login()
    {
            Pegawai q = (Pegawai) em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pegawai p").getSingleResult();

            //Query q = em.createQuery("select object(p) from Pegawai as p");
            /*if(!q.isEmpty()){
                return "app-main";
            }else{
                return "app-error";
            }*/
            //em.close();
            return "app-main";
    }
```

and this face-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>app-main</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/index.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>app-error</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/error.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>peg</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>Assets.Entities.PegawaiManager</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

when i hit login button, exception in page

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Assets.Entities.PegawaiManager.login(PegawaiManager.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
```

please help, why always exception when i did Query method ? i deployed with apache tomcat and mysql, mysql connector has added in library folder

Comment: Make sure you do not instantiate `EntityManager` manually, because that would make the injection to not work.
Edit: Where do you instantiate your `PegawaiManager`?

Comment: in this case, how to instantiate the EntityManager ? i'm sorry i'm beginner in JSF and java..please help @RaulGogo

Answer (score 0):

The error is at `Assets.Entities.PegawaiManager.login(PegawaiManager.java:114)`.

The only statement in login method is `Pegawai q = (Pegawai) em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pegawai p").getSingleResult();`

Make sure 'em' is not NULL.

Comment: how set 'em' not null ? i'm sorry, i'm beginner in jsf and java, i learned from tutorial and sample..thank you @Hardik Mishra

Answer (score -1):

You should try injecting the `EntityManagerFactory` and then creating from it an `EntityManager`.

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Then, obtain an EntityManager from the EntityManagerFactory instance:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: @PersistenceUnit 
EntityManagerFactory emf; 
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
Pegawai q = (Pegawai) em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pegawai p").getSingleResult();  but still exception..

Comment: <code>
    public PegawaiManager(){
       emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProjectAssetsPU");
       em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
    
    public String login()
        {
                Pegawai q = (Pegawai) em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pegawai p").getResultList();
                return "app-main";
        }
       </code>
and the exceptions
    <code>
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT p FROM Pegawai p]. Unknown entity type [Pegawai].</code>

Comment: Your table name is `@Table(name = "pegawai")`. Try setting it to capital letter : `@Table(name = "Pegawai")`

Comment: Thank you for the down-vote without explanation, whoever did it.